# Convert this cURL to pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, curl

I would like to convert the following cURL commands to pure JS:

```
curl -X POST \
-H "Content-Type: image/jpeg" \
--data-binary '@myPicture.jpg' \
https://parseapi.back4app.com/files/pic.jpg
```

So far, I was able to do the following:

```
  let postUrl = 'https://parseapi.back4app.com/files/'+picUrl;
  ParseHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
  return this.http.post(postUrl, {"name": "anything.jpg"}, {headers: ParseHeaders})
             .subscribe(
  (body:any) => {

    let res = JSON.parse(body._body);

  },
    error => console.log(error.json())
  );
```

But It doesn't work for me so far as I believe that I need to convert `--data-binary` too in order to make it work !